# Current regulator with controller?

Tags: microcontroller, current, adc, analog, low-pass

I want to implement a circuit which allows to regulate the current flowing to the load.

I have two use cases:

Case 1 is the normal case where I would set the max. allowed current with a potentiometer to say 5 amps and read the value into an ADC of the controller which then sets a specific duty cycle of the pwm. The low pass creates an analog value and give this to an amplifying buffer which lets current flow through the nmos. If the current (depending on the load) is below 5A, everything is fine, but once it raises above 5 amps, I want to lower the duty cycle to regulate the V_GS down, to reduce the current.

The other case is a short circuit protection, if the current raises way over 5A (like 8...10A) I want to shut off directly.

Is this concept going to work with a circuit like this?

[image: Regulator]

Answer (score 1):

It will basically work, but there are gotcha's:

- the DiffAmp, A/D microcontroller, PWM, low-pass-filter and buffer are all in the control loop, so they limit the response time, and you might need to ananlyse the loop behaviour to avoid oscillation
- to turn the FET on, you will need a voltage much higher than the 3.3V output of the PWM/low-pass/buffer. You might consider a BJT instead.
- the diffAmp must handle 0..20V inputs with a 3.3V supply. Might be tricky. If you can use a ground-based refernce (floating ground for your load) this will make things much easier.
- 5A with a 2Ohm load leaves 10V* 5A = 50W to burn in the transistor. Will keep you warm. Note that when the load can go to 0Ohm the transistor will dissipate 100W.

Comment: I'm thinking about using a charge-pmp to get the needed voltage to turn on the mosfet. The mosfet can withstand up to 300W so i don't really worry about it. What I worry about is the control loop you mentioned. I will need to shut off really quickly and I'm not exactly sure how quick it's going to be. The diff amp will amplify the voltage across the shunt I think which should be way lower than 3.3V, is that really a problem then?

Comment: Control loop stuff is tricky, I myself would either make it sufficiently slow, leave it to a specialist. Can de diff amp handle input voltage far outside its gnd-vcc range?? Your transistor might be able to handle the power, but check the small print in the datasheet: only with sufficient cooling!

Comment: That is my biggest concern,because the circuit has to be really fast. It should detect a short on the load and turn off in less than 15ms. But if the current is already as high, I probably won't regulate anything and just shut the mosfet off. The mosfet is a bts282z, quite a beast I think.

Comment: 15ms is not that fast for electronics, but I am no expert on this. Even the biggest mosfet will cook itself to death without appropriate cooling.

Comment: As drawn, the diff amp will see 20 volts on its inputs.  If it has a 3.3 volts power supply, it probably won't survive, and definitely won't provide a useful output.  Perhaps you could use a Hall-effect current sensor instead of the shunt and diff amp.

Comment: But the difference between the terminals would be just 100mV @ 10A. If I give him an amp factor of 10 he only has to output 1 volt or not? Of course there will be resistors around the op amp which will make it into a substractor with a very low of amplification (which makes it into a diff amp)

Comment: @Canbus: again: most OpAmps and DiffAmps can only handle input voltages that fall in the 0..Vcc range, in your case 0..3.3V. I am not talking about the difference between the inputs, but about their absolute valules.

Comment: So this means i have to put the input voltage, say 20V as my power supply for my op amp. How can I prevent my microcontroller from frying in case the current gets actually really big? The order is still: first the current goes up, then, after sampling the micro knows that it's too high and could turn it off, but it could be fried by then.

Comment: There are numerous solutions. Find a diff-amp that can realy handle 0-20V inputs with 3.3V power (I dunno if one exists, but it could). Put the resistor at ground. Divide both voltage down to the range 0-3.3V. Use a Diff-amp with a current source output. etc. etc.